# Duplicating Unity's mystic Interface power

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity3D has an interface like this, for any Component on a MonoBehavior you just do this:

```
public class LaraCroft:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler
  {
  public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("With no other effort, this function is called
        for you, by the Unity engine, every time someone touches
        the glass of your iPhone or Android.");
        }
```

You **do not** have to register, set a delegate or anything else. OnPointerDown (the only item in IPointerDownHandler) gets called for you every single time someone touches the screen.

Amazing!

Here's a similar interface I wrote ...

```
public interface ISingleFingerDownHandler
    {
    void OnSingleFingerDown();
    }
```

Now, I want consumers to be able to do this...

```
public class LaraCroft:MonoBehaviour,ISingleFingerDownHandler
    {
    public void OnSingleFingerDown(PointerEventData data)
        {
        Debug.Log("this will get called every time
        the screen is touched...");
        }
```

Just to recap, using Unity's interface, the function gets called automatically with *no further effort* - the consumer does *not* have to register or anything else.

Sadly, I can achieve that only like this:

I write a "daemon" ..

```
public class ISingleFingerDaemon:MonoBehaviour
    {
    private ISingleFingerDownHandler needsUs = null;
    // of course that would be a List,
    // just one shown for simplicity in this example code

    void Awake()
        {
        needsUs = GetComponent(typeof(ISingleFingerDownHandler))
                                       as ISingleFingerDownHandler;
        // of course, this could search the whole scene,
        // just the local gameobject shown here for simplicity
        }

    ... when something happens ...

        if (needsUs != null) needsUs.OnSingleFingerDown(data);


    }
```

And I get that daemon running somewhere.

If you're not a Unity user - what it does is looks around for and finds any of the `ISingleFingerDownHandler` consumers, keeps a list of them, and then appropriately calls `OnPointerDown` as needed. This works fine BUT

- the consumer-programmer has to remember to "put the daemon somewhere" and get it running etc.
- there are obvious anti-elegancies whenever you do something like this (in Unity or elsewhere), re efficiency, placement, etc etc

• this approach fails of course if a consumer comes in to existence at a time when the daemon is not searching for them (Unity's magic interfaces don't suffer this problem - they have more magic to deal with that)

(PS, I know how to write an automatic helper that places the daemon and so on: please do not reply in that vein, thanks!)

Indeed, obviously the developers at Unity have some system going on behind the scenes, which does all that beautifully because "their" interfaces are perfectly able to call all the needed calls, regardless of even items being created on the fly etc.

What's the best solution? Am I stuck with needing a daemon? And perhaps having to register?

(It would surely suck - indeed generally not be usable in typical Unity projects - to just make it a class to inherit from; that type of facility is naturally an interface.)

So to recap,  Unity has this:

```
public class LaraCroft:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler
```

Surely there's a way for me to make a replacement, extension, for that...

```
public class LaraCroft:MonoBehaviour,ISuperiorPointerDownHandler
```

which can then be used the same way / which shares the magic qualities of that interface?  I can do it fine, but only my making a daemon.

### Update

Full solution for "ISingleFingerHandler" "IPinchHandler" and similar concepts in Unity is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591301/294884

Comment: Just reading this - yes plus one. I came up with my roll-my-own message system, that requires a component in each object that listens for an event from the messenger that fires the Execute method on that object for a particular interface. It's a bunch of boilerplate code, that works great once implemented.

Comment: Indeed @ChuckSavage, quite right. For anyone reading through all this, I have come to the carefully considered opinion that it's best to just "subclass", as it were, Unity's IPointerDown/etc concepts, and just trivially have your own daemon. (Which is no different from what we all do all the time in Unity code: ie, it's a completely false path trying to make it "like" Unity's system.)  The end result is **ridiculously simple**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40591301/294884  Link includes an epic discussion of why it's the way to go.  (Setting aside the obvious "incredibly simple and elegant".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but the answer here is really:

## You cannot. You *do* have to add a daemon.

But then, it's very much worth noting that

## Indeed, *Unity add a daemon* - they just hide it a little.

The final absolutely critical point to understand is that:

## Unity screwed-up: you *cannot in fact* inherit from their lovely StandAloneInputModule. This is a big mistake.

Unity's StandAloneInputModule and IPointerDownHandler family - are brilliant. But you can't inherit from them properly.

The fact is, you just have to inherit sideways from IPointerDownHandler. That's all there is to it.

## The fact is you have to make your own daemon ("as if" it inherits from StandAloneInputModule) which actually just goes sideways from IPointerDownHandler family.

So the actual answer is (A) you have this

```
public interface ISingleFingerHandler
    {
    void OnSingleFingerDown (Vector2 position);
    void OnSingleFingerUp (Vector2 position);
    void OnSingleFingerDrag (Vector2 delta);
    }

public class SingleFingerInputModule:MonoBehaviour,
                IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler,IDragHandler
```

and (B) you *do* have to put that on a game object (it's a daemon), and then (C) it's just stupidly easy to finally handle pinches, etc.

```
public class YourFingerClass:MonoBehaviour, IPinchHandler
    {
    public void OnPinchZoom (float delta)
        {
        _processPinch(delta);
        }
```

That's it!

Full production code for `PinchInputModule` ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591301/294884

...which indeed inherits sideways from ("uses") IPointerDownHandler family.

Answer (score 4):

You say you don't want to do a daemon but that is exactly what Unity is doing. The [`StandaloneInputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.html) class that is automatically added when you add a UI component ***is that daemon***.

[image]

What you can do is create a new class derived from one of the classes derived from [`BaseInputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.BaseInputModule.html) (likey [`PointerInputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerInputModule.html) for your case) that can handle listening to trigger and raising your extra events then add that new class to the EventSystem object.

See the Unity manual section on the [Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) for notes on how to create your custom events and more details on what the input module does.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't see a way of doing this without calling it somehow or attaching it to an active GameObject.

Comment: Hmm, the one and only discussion I can find about extending PointerInputModule (or similar) is http://unity-coding.slashgames.org/extend-unitys-eventsystem-drag-drop/

Comment: Tim C's example here is possibly the way to go: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/event-system-onenable-or-start.266354/

Comment: This writer ... https://community.unity.com/t5/Unity-UI/EventSystem/m-p/1827986  ... works at a low level to program a pinch: but that strikes me as very problematic: if you start with the power of OnPointerDown / etc and extend that functionality (somehow), all you have to do is add a few lines of logic.

Comment: One through refrence implmentation you can use for making your own input module is the one from [Oculus's example framework](https://developer3.oculus.com/downloads/game-engines/1.5.1/Oculus_Sample_Framework_for_Unity_5_Rift_Executable/), here is a link to a copy of [the specific script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f75a852b87857f2f666a0058a90422b1)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks for that, good one. One problem is (as I allude to in the previous), it seems "ridiculously non OO".  a HUGE amount of work has been done in making the `OnPointerDown` and friends calls work flawlessly. All I want to do is add some trivial functionality very much on top of that; in contrast the method Unity uses and others use is to "entire copy and paste the huge slab of that class, and modify the ones you want to modify". It just seems like poor engineering.  (I'll put in a new question explicitly about this issue.) Note too that the only advantage is....

Comment: ... seems to be that you can use the handy "Execute."... call (which seems little different than just looping over your own list).  Tricky issues ... :/

Comment: Thanks a billion for your input on this issue @ScottChamberlain. (I really only understood the issues due to your comments.) I lose sleep over things like this. In the end I've decided just writing your own handler (essentially: "subclassing" Unity's) is best, and I outline why at extreme length here :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/40591301/294884  Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that MonoBehaviour runs a type check in ctor. Which is why you cannot use the ctor on those to avoid overriding that process. The common solution is that your interface would also require to implement a registering method (Vuforia does that for instance) so any new instance registers itself.

You could also extend MB class with your own MB system:

```
public class JoeMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
     protected virtual void Awake(){
         Init();
     }
     private void Init(){
         if(this is ISuperiorPointerDownHandler)
         {
              if(ISuperiorHandler.Instance != null){
                   ISuperiorHandlerInstance.RegisterPointerDownHandler(this as ISuperiorPointerDownHandler);
              }
         }
     }
}
```

It does not have the magic of Unity but you cannot achieve the magic of Unity with MonoBehaviour. It require the sub class to make sure it calls the base.Awake() if overriding it.

You'd have to come up with your own side engine system to run your own engine logic. Not sure that'd be worth it.

Another solution is to create your own Instantiate:

```
namespace JoeBlowEngine{
    public static GameObject Instantiate(GameObject prefab, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation){
          GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation);
          MonoBehaviour [] mbs = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<MonoBehaviour>(true); // I think it should also get all components on the parent object
          foreach(MonoBehaviour mb in mbs){
                CheckForSuperior(mb);
                CheckForInferior(mb);
                // so on...
          }
          return obj;
    }
    internal static CheckForSuperior(MonoBehaviour mb)
    {
         if(mb is SomeType) { SomeTypeHandler.Instance.Register(mb as SomeType); }
    }
}
```

Now it look like you are doing some magic only with :

```
 JoeBlowEngine.Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question thoroughly. He said he doesn't ant to call it anywhere. He just wants the event to start working which I think is impossible. It most be started somewhere. Look at the quote from his question -  **"PS, I know how to write an automatic helper that places the daemon and so on: please do not reply in that vein, thanks"** I think this is what you just did.

Comment: The OP does not need an answer coz he can do it himself but I beg to think that this is meant to be used by others, not necessarily people with 10+ years programming. If not so, then answer is simple. "No can-do, next".

Comment: Programmer is quite right that that is what I was trying to avoid.  However, **excellent point Everts** that - of course - the "registering function" can just be one of the calls required by the interface - that's awesome.

Comment: @Programmer and Ev.  Notice TimC's example here https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/event-system-onenable-or-start.266354/ ... maybe that's the way to go.  What a lot of spaghetti.

Comment: TimC's example is exactly what I did [here[(http://stackoverflow.com/a/40571106/3785314) on the second solution in `PointerCounterEventData .cs`. You still have to call it from somewhere. It won't start or call it self unless I am missing something else. I will Unity would add a callback function that will be called on a script that is not attached to any GameObject. That would solve your problem.

Comment: Wait man 0- are you extending `StandAloneInputModule` or indeed BaseInputModule or PointerInputModule ........ that seems to be the core of the issue.  Indeed (I think) it does just what you say ...... for me it seems a bit shambolic though.  Notice Tim C's example here: forum.unity3d.com/threads/event-system-onenable-or-start.266‌​354 and the other examples mentioned under Scott's answer above......

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I didn't get notification. I extended `BaseEventData`  in that answer. As for `StandAloneInputModule ` and `BaseInputModule`  or `PointerInputModule` they all won't solve your problem.  The [linked solution](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/event-system-onenable-or-start.266354/) requires you to have GameObjects you want to send events to in the `m_TargetObjects` variable array. It does not send automatically to every GameObject. If you find a solution or make one out of that linked answer, please let me know.

Comment: **YES** @Programmer - I utterly agree with what you just said: *"requires you to have .. does not send automatically .."*  **EXACTLY**.  You are 10000% correct. That's the critical point.  For me now, in all real cases it would simply be wrong to copy-paste-mod Unity's code in a hunt for a "StandAloneInputModule-like" solution, which is a chimera. In the end I believe the incredibly simple approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40591301/294884 is best.  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow Really don't know. Sometimes, it shows the chat link. Other times, it doesn't. At this moment, it does not.

Comment: I will today. I think I forgot to do that last week. I don't really know about the exact time but will do that today. Plan to take a nap in few minutes. Will see you then.